# How to make IN on values from cell?

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, csv, join

I have table which contains list of data ceparated by coma 
eg

```
deputy
1,2,3
2
4,6
```

I am trying to left joint it with IN clause, but without success

```
LEFT JOIN chat_user AS du
    ON du.chat_user_id  IN (message_item.deputy)
```

Comment: You cannot use `IN` for this purpose.  You have to play with `LIKE`.  Better - normalize your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses string functions:

```
left join chat_user as du
    on ',' || message_item.deputy || ',' like '%,' || du.chat_user_id  || ',%'
```